# How to use Any() with System.Linq.Dynamic?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, entity-framework-4

I have an example with two tables - Movies and Genders. The relationship is N:N so I have in Movies a collection of Genders and in Genders a collection of Movies.

I am using `System.Linq.Dynamic` to create my query and I would like to know how to get all the movies that at least one of its gender is in a list of genders (the parameters of search).

I try to do something like this:

```
Genders.Any(x => lstGenders.Contains(x))
```

But I get an exception that there does not exist an `x` field in `Genders`.

Is it possible to all the movies that at least has a gender that is in the list?

Comment: What is `Genders` a collection of? Something simple like a `List<String>` or is it a class you created?

Comment: it should probably be `genre` and not `gender`?

Comment: Any() will only return true/false if any elements in the source meet the condtion you specified so you probably don't want to use that. I would have thought you would want to try something like Movies.Where(x => lstGenders.Contains(x.Gender). Also you shouldn't use hungarian notation and Chips_100 is correct (should be Genre).